# Performance of python list count method

Tags: python, performance

In python, it's very easy to get the count of a particular item in a list:

```
>>> L = [1,1,1,2,3,4]
>>> print(L.count(1))
3
```

Is this method O(N)? Is it advisable to use this method, or are there better ways of quickly getting the count of an arbitrary number of elements in a list (i.e. a way to avoid O(mN), where m is the number of records for which a call to `count` is required).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) if you need to count more than one time through the iterable.  Then you will only have to iterate once.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> counter = Counter('hellooo i am a potato!!!!!')
>>> counter.most_common(2)
[('o', 5), ('!', 5)]
```